# Formatting not being applied to hompage

Tags: formatting

If you visit [my site](http://thezenapproach.com) you can see that the teasers on the homepage are not formatted correctly as compared to every other page. I'm guessing that it is because it is the only page without a heading. Anyone care to take a look using firebug or something? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. it looks like you have some messed up markup.  i am seeing a lot of empty  tags

and 2. .custom .teaser has a negative margin-top on style.css lines 730 and 750.  make that a positive ... say 22px and the site looks normal again.